# getting the image in bitmap but returning black pixels only

Tags: android, imageview, android-bitmap

I am tried to set the image bitmap it was showing black pixels and i also tried Image URI but again setting black pixels But when i debugged it , the bitmap and uri image are getting the correct image but both the method are not able to set it in imageview.

```
`ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imagef);
    try
    {
        String profileImagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/MYFolder/"+ Configuration.empcode+".jpg";
        File profilepath = new File(profileImagePath);
        if(profilepath.exists())
        {

            //need to resolve
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(profileImagePath);

            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(profileImagePath));
//                imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            imageView.setImageURI(uri);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("Profile Image Exception", e.toString());
    }
`
```

see the image here

[image: the bitmap value and imageview value]

Comment: What is the file lenght of that jpg file? And it's resolution? Check if `bmp` is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imagef);
String profileImagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/MYFolder/"+ Configuration.empcode+".jpg";
File profilepath = new File(profileImagePath);
Picasso.with(activity_or_fragment_context).load(profilePath).placeholder(R.drawable.any_place_holder_png_file).fit().centerCrop().into(imageView);
```

Comment: Just got it working .
can you please explain me why that was happening (Black Pixels)
Thank you very much

Comment: Because Picasso resizes the picture. You were not doing that. Your original is so big thst BitmapFactoty.decodeFile returns null.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Picasso:

```
    String profileImagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/MYFolder/"+ Configuration.empcode+".jpg";
    File profilepath = new File(profileImagePath);
    Picasso.with(yourActivityContext).load(profilepath).into(imageView);
```